# Excel JavaScript custom function starting twice after loading spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, office-js, custom-functions-excel

After loading a spreadsheet that contains a cell with a custom function reference, the custom function appears to be loaded twice. Can this be avoided?

To reproduce the issue for Excel Desktop:

1. Create a folder and run `yo office --projectType excel-functions --name 'TestAddin' --host excel --js`
2. Change to folder `TestAddIn` and run `npm run build`, then `npm start`
3. Allow some time for the plugin to compile and Excel to start, then select a spreadsheet cell and type `=CONTOSO.INCREMENT(1)` into the Excel formula bar. Press `Enter`.
4. You should now see the cell showing incrementing values.
5. Save the spreadsheet and close Excel.
6. Re-open the spreadsheet.

Over time, the cell shows:

```
#BUSY
1
2
3
#BUSY
1
2
3
4
...
```

Note that this is not using the shared runtime. A similar issue is logged here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/847.

Comment: I was able to repro the issue. I'm not sure about a workaround, but you should report this issue on the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular issue seems to be related to running the example under the debugger, see: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1714